# Matlab. Write text file or create it if it doesn't exist. Save figures in directory or create it if it doesn't exist

Tags: matlab, fopen, save-as

I have two similar question but for a different purpose.

1) How can i tell matlab to write on a text file and if doesn't exist, to create it? The basic code to improve would be something like:

```
fileID = fopen('results.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID, 'Name\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%%variation\t\tSteady-state\n');
fclose(fileID);
```

1) Same thing but for when I save figures, I want to save them in a sub-directory of the working one, but if it doesn't exist it should create it. The basic code to improve would be something like:

```
fig=figure; set(fig, 'Visible', 'off');
plot(...); xlabel(...); ylabel(...); legend(...);
saveas(fig,s3)
```

where s3 is

```
s3 = char(strcat(s1(1),'.png')); %concatenate .png and convert to string
```

How can I tell it to save to a different directory?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your first code works fine if the file does not exist, and run away the content if the file exists. I suppose that the first problem is that you want to preserve the content if the file exists already, so:

```
if exist('results.txt')==2
  fileID = fopen('results.txt','a'); % open exist file and append contents
else
  fileID = fopen('results.txt','w'); % create file and write to it
end
```

For the second question:

```
if exist('SubDir')~=7  % if there is not a sub-directory named "SubDir", make it
  mkdir('SubDir');
end
saveas(fig,fullfile('SubDir',s3))
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much.
Now that it works I only need to create an interface from where the user can choose the path ^^'.
It is going to take me some time. Thanks again

Comment: If you want to let the user choose the path, use `uiegtdir`- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetdir.html